# Accumulate predictions in output tensor for Google Cloud serving

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, tensorflow-estimator

I'm new to TF and trying to deploy [Quick, Draw!](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/recurrent_quickdraw) model on Google Cloud.
It uses custom `Estimator` and takes 1 `tfexample` and returns classification tensor of shape `(8)`. 
One of the requirements for models to be deployed is that input and output tensors should support batching, e.g. their outer dimensions should be `None`.

Doing so for input tensor is easy since we have `serving_input_receiver_fn` under control, as for output tensor I'm confused because whether I change output tensor I also need to refactor whole train/evaluate operation. Are there any shortcuts to accomplish that?

Comment: Using the Quick, Draw! sample code as an example, note that the estimator's prediction (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/quickdraw/train_model.py#L245) carries the same batch dimension as the input.  So it should work without having to modify the training.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to confirm that indeed the output from a saved model exported from a TensorFlow estimator will carry the same batch size as the input.

There are a few caveats if you try to export and deploy this particular tutorial to Google Cloud's AI Platform Prediction service though:

- The `model_fn` needs to be updated to handle the `PREDICT` mode properly.
- The Prediction service actually requires the outer dimension to be `None` in the saved model, this also requires some code change in the tutorial since it specifies the batch size.
- The tutorial code does not include the call to `estimator.export_saved_model`, in particular you'll need to implement a `serving_input_receiver_fn`.
- There seems to be a bug in TF that causes restoration of `cudnn_lstm` to fail: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23898.  So in particular at the moment if the model is trained with `cudnn_lstm` it can't be deployed as a saved model.

I have made these changes to the tutorial in a fork: https://github.com/dizcology/models/tree/quickdraw-gcp/tutorials/rnn